# How to Execute specific method defined in Windows service based on values present in database

Tags: c#, database, windows-services

I want to make windows service which contains methods and one of the method reads data from database..Now as per my need i have to execute a specific method from the methods defined in Windows service based on the value got from the database at the

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
```

of the web service ..

Now my doubts are:

1. Is it possible to read values from database first and then execute the method at the OnStart of the web service.

2.Based on the value of the database it will call particular method which will execute the data processing and storing in the database continuously..

Please Guide me.
Thanks in advance..